# create-react-app is not using my eslint configuration file

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, eslint, create-react-app

I am using create-react-app to start a new react project, and I want to use my own eslint configuration file, extending from the react-app one.

It seems like my **.eslintrc** file is not used at all, even though I placed it in the root folder. In my output terminal I can see the file is loaded from the node_modules folder:

> .../node_modules/eslint/lib/api.js

Am I missing something, or should I save the file somewhere else?

Thanks.

[image: VSCode screenshot]

Comment: Create-react-app is a solution to use without override. If you want to use your own configuration yu have to eject and that's not as easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

True, those files are not used by create-react-app.

It is still possible to disable ESLint rules using comments in the JavaScript files:

// eslint-disable-next-line react/style-prop-object

For more information see: http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring.html#configuring-rules

Comment: Thanks @Bjorn, I saw the possibility to add comments in files, but I wanted to have a more global solution. Is it possible to remove the eslint configuration shipped with create-react-app and add my own? In react-native I used npm install eslint-config-rallycoding.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, now it is available by setting the `EXTEND_ESLINT` env variable. But the feature is experimental right now.

See the [Experimental: Extending the ESLint config](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/setting-up-your-editor) section.